# Horizontally center content of a scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a standard view embedded inside a scroll view and I am using Auto Layout. All is working fine, and I am almost done with it. There is just one small problem. My content view has a fixed height of 536 points, so in an iPhone 6 it is fully displayed without the need of scrolling, while in an iPhone 4S I have to scroll to view additional content.

My problem is that the view is not horizontally centered is the iPhone 6 so it displays the extra space at the bottom (I filled it with grey color for clarity), as shown in the picture below (that is the underlying scroll view).

[image: scroll view]

My question is: how can I horizontally center the content view without messing up the constraints? Currently the scroll view is pinned at the four borders of the view controller and the content view is pinned to the four borders of the scroll view.

I am glad to provide any other information you need to help me solve the problem.

EDIT: This is what it worked for me

```
CGFloat superViewHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height;

if (superViewHeight > scrollViewHeight)
    self.topConstraint.constant += (superViewHeight - scrollViewHeight) / 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should manually adjust top constraint if your content view doesn't need scrolling.

```
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.bounds);
CGFloat contentViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(contentView.bounds);

if (scrollViewHeight >= contentViewHeight)
{
    topConstraint.constant += ((scrollViewHeight - contentViewHeight) / 2.f);
}
```

Comment: What is `topConstraint`?

Comment: It's the constraint between `scrollView`'s top and `contentView`'s top.

Comment: Well, it didn't work, and I think I know why: `scrollView` and  `contentView` already have the same height, i.e. they're both 536 points tall, but iPhone 6 screen is taller (about 670pt), so that could be a problem.

Comment: First add some constraints to your scroll view to fit its superview, then it should work.

Comment: I finally made it. I had to modify the constraint that binds the scroll view to the superview, instead of the content view. So I get the superview height, `superViewHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height`, and I subtract the `scrollViewContent` from it. For some reason, though, I had to divide the result by 4. Could you please explain me why?

Comment: Can you confirm `superviewHeight` and `contentViewHeight` are correct? And please also confirm `topConstraint` doesn't have `multiplier = 2`. If both are OK, please post the full code.

Comment: Yes, I confirm the values are as expected and `multiplier = 1`. Where should I post the full code? I don't think it's suitable to post it in comments.

Comment: You can update the question, I guess. I suspect your navigation bar is transparent and so you might end up getting `superviewHeight = actualHeight + navigationBarHeight`.

Comment: Nope. Navigation bar is not translucent and I correctly have the Top Layout Guide underneath it. Provided the full code in the question.

Comment: I've tried to implement something similar to this and it works. So you definitely have a problem with the height calculation or top constraint. I need to do some debugging to understand. I leave the rest to you. Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.